# Matching one or more alphanumeric characters with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app. Why does the pattern `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/` match an empty string?

```
<form name="addTeamForm" novalidate ng-init="team=''">
  <input type="text" name="team" ng-model="team" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/"/>
</form>
{{ addTeamForm.team.$valid }}
```

Why the value of `$valid` is `true`?

http://jsfiddle.net/NameFILIP/fdsqzf12/5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to also use `required` or `ngRequired`:

```
<input type="text" name="team" ng-model="team" 
       ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/" required />
```

The way `ngPattern` work is to check not empty string to match a pattern. If string is empty it won't be checked and no validation error will arise. By specifying `required` directive in addition to ngPattern you are making empty string invalid value.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vittore/fdsqzf12/6/

Comment: Even if it's not required, it still doesn't match the pattern

Comment: Check updated fiddle. Try to enter `!`. It does match.

Comment: It turn's out that the patten directive checks if the input is empty or matches the pattern. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/dd2a803f4f03ab629a51623c026d3e3f9dc9e91f/src/ng/directive/input.js#L2319

Comment: That is what I meant, yes.